# Calling a Tk instance from another Tk instance causes issue setting textvariables

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

I have built a simple user dropdown menu using `Tkinter` and `ttk`. I use `textvariable.set()` to set a default value for the window on loading. Everything works great. Code is below.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
parent = Tk()

myvalue = StringVar()

user_entry1 = ttk.Combobox(parent, values=['value 1', 'value2'], textvariable=myvalue)
user_entry1.pack()
myvalue.set('default value')
mainloop()
```

I now want to get a bit more complicated and use another `Tk()` instance, called `root` to to generate my `parent` `Tk()` instance. Everything seems to work fine, expect the default value for the dropdown doesn't get display. It does get assigned to the textvariable as proven by `print myvalue.get()`. What am I missing here?

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

root = Tk()

def load_dropdown():
    parent = Tk()
    myvalue = StringVar()

    user_entry1 = ttk.Combobox(parent, values=['value 1', 'value2'], textvariable=myvalue)
    user_entry1.pack()
    myvalue.set('default value')
    print myvalue.get()
    parent.mainloop()

b = Button(root, text="Generate Dropdown ", command=load_dropdown)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two `Tk` instances confuses it. If you want things displayed in a separate top-level window, call [`Toplevel()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) instead and things will work.

```
def load_dropdown():
    parent = Toplevel()  # <- change to this
    myvalue = StringVar()
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use more than once instance of `Tk` in a tkinter application. You are observing one of the negative side-effects of trying to do so.

If you need a second window, create an instance of [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) rather than a second instance of `Tk`.

Answer (score 1):

In tkinter you only ever create one mainloop which is done by
    root = Tk()

This is your default window. Your example will work if you get rid of the second creation of parent.

To create more windows use new_window = TopLevel()

There is a lot of good documentation on tkinter, make use of it and it will take you far :)

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm

http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html

http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html

https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html