# Tkinter open new Form inside Existing Form, Attribute ERROR

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am making a simple Gui using Tkinter, how to open the window in "initia(self)" by button click. How to open a new Window inside the Existing Interface. NOT new Window (if possible), I have imported necessary packages (Tkinter (I am using Python 2.7), PIL, tkMessageBox, tkFont and tkFileDialog) I am NOOB in GUI....

```
class main1(Tkinter.Tk):
def __init__(self, parent):
    Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.initialize()
def initialize(self):
    self.geometry("600x210")
    self.configure(bg="#00bbdc")    
    helv36 = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica',size=16, weight='bold')
    self.hello = Tkinter.Label(self, text="MAIN MENU", font=helv36).grid(row=1, column=2)


    self.cont = Tkinter.Button(self,text="Forgot Password",font=helv36,fg='aquamarine4', command=self.initia,padx=10, pady=10)
    h = self.cont
    h.grid(row=3, column=2,padx=10)
    h.config(bd=8, relief='raised')


def initia(self): """ This Function shows Attribute Error, How can I define THIS in a Class """
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    # frame = Tkinter.Frame(self.root, bd=2, relief='raised')
    self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    xscroll = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal')
    self.xscroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
    yscroll = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self)
    self.yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
    canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(self, bd=0, xscrollcommand=xscroll.set, yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
    self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    self.xscroll.config(command=canvas.xview)
    self.yscroll.config(command=canvas.yview)
    self.pack(fill='both',expand=1)

    #adding the image
    File = askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir="C:/",title='Choose an image.')
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(File))
    self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=img,anchor="nw")
    self.canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

    #function to be called when mouse is clicked
    def printcoords(event):
        #outputting x and y coords to console
        print (event.x,event.y)
    #mouseclick event
    canvas.bind("<Button 1>",printcoords)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = main1(None)
    app.title('Main Form')
    app.mainloop()
```

How can I put the function "initia(self)" to a new Class

Comment: You are trying to create a second instance of `Tkinter.Tk` in `initia`. This will not work. Look for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248376/calling-a-tk-instance-from-another-tk-instance-causes-issue-setting-textvariable/31250112#31250112)

Comment: So another instances cannot be opened in same window ??

Comment: Read the link carefully. Correct wording: Another instance cannot be **created** in same **program**.

Comment: ThankYou , But I changed `root=Tk()` to `root=Toplevel()` still the Error occurs !!!

Comment: Error? What error? You don't mention any error in your question

Comment: `Attribute ERROR : initia` This is the Error, I mentioned it in Title, and in Code

Comment: I don't get `Attribute ERROR : initia` but I get `AttributeError: xscroll`. This is because you assign the Scrollbar to `xscroll` and then try to access it as `self.xscroll`. Same for `yscroll`.